# Calculating Fourier series of $\cos^2(t)$ gives unexpected result

Tags: fourier-series, wolfram-alpha

As I understand it:

$\cos^2(t)$ is even because it is a product of two even functions $\cos(t)$.

The Fourier series and Fourier cosine series of an even function is the same [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierCosineSeries.html).

So in the fourier series expansion $\cos^2(t)={a_0 \over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n\cos(n \omega t) + b_n \sin(n \omega t))$, I expect $a_n\neq 0$ and $b_n=0$.

I try to get the the coefficients with wolfram alpha like this:

$a_n$ with FourierCosCoefficient[$\cos(t)^2,t,n$] gives zero [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierCosCoefficient%5Bcos(t)%5E2,t,n%5D)

$b_n$ with FourierSinCoefficient[$\cos(t)^2,t,n$] gives non-zero [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierSinCoefficient%5Bcos(t)%5E2,t,n%5D)

Which of my assumptions are wrong?

(I also got $a_n=0$ when calculating by hand so the question is not primarily about wolfram alpha but about the relation between Fourier series, Fourier cosine series, and even functions)

Comment: Looks to me that already $a_0 = \frac{1}{2} \ne 0$... Can you detail your computations ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with WolframAlpha to say, but it seems to me this is likely to be a misunderstanding of what the function does. For example, where's the $\omega$ in that call? Maybe it's trying to project the function on a different period?

As it stands, $cos^2(t) = 1/2+1/2cos(2t)$, so that's all your Fourier series.

Comment: The correct answer is $a_0=a_2=\frac 1 2$ and all other coefficients $0$.

Comment: Surprisingly Mathematica gives the same answer. OTOH to the integral `FourierCosCoefficient[(1+Cos[2t])/2,t,n]`it gives the expected `(DiscreteDelta[n-2]+2 DiscreteDelta[n])/2`

Comment: And also `FourierCosCoefficient [Cos[t]^2,t,0]` and `FourierCosCoefficient [Cos[t]^2,t,2]` ae calculated correctly.

Comment: FWIW, I asked this at [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192933/1155).

Comment: `FourierTrigSeries[cos(t)^2,t,n]` gives `1/2,1/2,(1/2)cos(2t)+1/2,(1/2)cos(2t)+1/2`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to find the Fourier series of this function is to write it as $\frac {1+\cos(2t)} 2$. This expression is in fact the Fourier series!.

Comment: I'm sure we all know this. The question is why WolframAlpha gives a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the documentation:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinCoefficient.html

The command FourierSinCoefficient does not compute the coefficients $b_n$ in the full Fourier series, but the coefficients in the Fourier **sine** series (= the full Fourier series of the **odd extension** of the function in question).

Comment: Thanks, this shows why I was wrong to assume I could calculate $b_n$ with FourierSinCoefficient. I still think I should be able to calculate $a_n$ with FourierCosCoefficient.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2(t)\sin(nt)\,\mathrm dt=0,$$since $t\mapsto\cos^2(t)\sin(nt)$ is an odd function.

On the other hand,$$a_0=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2(t)\,\mathrm dt=1\neq0.$$It turns out that $a_1=0$, but $a_2=\frac12\neq0$.

Comment: I'm sure we all know this. The question is why WolframAlpha gives a different answer.

Comment: No, we don't *all* know this, since the OP claimed to have obtained $a_n=0$ while calculating by hand.